# Some faces of a model don't respond to UV Mapping

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I can't seem to get these particular faces to take the UV Mapping. I selected the entire object, entered edit mode, hit <kbd>U</kbd>>*Unwrap*.

The rest of the mesh takes the uv wrapping, but not those faces for some reason.

[image: model showing the UV map]

It looks normal in solid mode.

[image: model with solid shading]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: I think you didn't assign the texture to all the mesh, try to select all UV islands in UV/Image editor and select the image from the browser, the small image icon on the bottom of the UV/Image editor window.

Comment: Awesome diagnosis Denis. That seems to have worked brilliantly. Thank you so much for your quick response. This has been thwarting me for a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some of the faces were not selected while assigning the texture.**

To avoid that problem, make sure all UV islands are selected when creating or assigning a texture, or select all the UV islands and reassign the texture again from image browser: the small image icon on the bottom of the UV/Image editor window.

[image]

Comment: Denis' solution worked for me. "I think you didn't assign the texture to all the mesh, try to select all UV islands in UV/Image editor and select the image from the browser, the small image icon on the bottom of the UV/Image editor window. – Denis 8 " Thanks again Denis.